# How To Prevent Adding Duplicate row to a DevExpress gridControl

Tags: duplicates, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a gridcontrol bind to Datatable, in my grid i let users to select products for proccessing.

The issue is I don't want users to add same product code twice to the grid.

Is there a way to prevent them adding the same product code twice?

I already tried Unique attirbute in my DataTable bu it didn't quite worked as I needed.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: you might want to set a filter to the product lookup

Answer (score 1):

I normally use GridView.ValidateRow event which should fire when the user has finished editing a row.  Event args provides access to the row object via e.Row, an error message via e.ErrorText, and valid status via e.Valid, so it should be a simple matter of grabbing the product code from the updated row and looking for it in the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of something like this

```
 gridViewDefault.RowLoaded += gridViewDefault_RowLoaded;

 Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable();
        void gridViewDefault_RowLoaded(object sender, RowEventArgs e)
        {
            var obj = ( sender as GridView ).GetRow(e.RowHandle) as OrderDocument;
            var uniqueId = obj.Document.DocumentId;
            if( hashTable[uniqueId] == null )
                hashTable.Add(uniqueId, 1);
            else
                ( sender as GridView ).DeleteRow(e.RowHandle);
        }
```

but then saw that the RowLoaded event only fires in [Instant Feedback Mode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument8893)

Apparently there is no immediate event after a DataSource has finised Loading.

Therefore, instead of event-based, I would go for a function similar to the one I wrote, which Iterates the whole GridView, after you have all the Data.